# Ruby: how to smush 2D array based on value of one of the elements

Tags: ruby, arrays

In Ruby I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
[["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""],
 ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "", "ABC Team"],
 ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "", "Global Design"],
 ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "", "Jones, Fred"],
 ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", "Finance"],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "Escalated", ""]]
```

I would like to smush the entries together based on the timestamp.  I would like the resulting array to look like:

```
[["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""],
 ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "Escalated", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "Escalated", "ABC Team"],
 ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "Escalated", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "Escalated", "Global Design"],
 ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "Escalated", "Jones, Fred"],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "Escalated", "Finance"]]
```

Any ideas of an efficient way to accomplish this in Ruby?

Comment: Enumerable's group_by is your friend here.

Comment: Your question is not clear. When are empty strings eliminated? It only looks arbitrary. What determines the order of the elements that follow the time stamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and then fix up the grouped values:

```ruby
def smush_array(arr)
  arr.group_by(&:first).map do |k,v|
    row = [k, v.last[1]] + v[0..-1].sort.map(&:last).uniq
  end.map {|x| (x.size > 3) ? x.reject(&:empty?) : x}
end

smushed = smush_array(array)
# [["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""],
#  ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "Escalated", "Smith, Bob"],
#  ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "Escalated", "ABC Team"],
#  ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "Escalated", "Smith, Bob"],
#  ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "Escalated", "Global Design"],
#  ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "Escalated", "Jones, Fred"],
#  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "Escalated", "Finance"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it, but this seems to be a solution:

```
data = [["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""],
 ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "", "ABC Team"],
 ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "", "Global Design"],
 ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "", "Jones, Fred"],
 ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "Escalated", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", "Finance"],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "Escalated", ""]]

map = {}

data.each do |input|
 map[input[0]] ||= [] 
 map[input[0]].concat(input[1..input.length].reject{|item| item.empty?})
end

result = []
map.each do |k,v|
  result << [k].concat(v)
end

puts result.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [
  ["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""],
  ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "", "Smith, Bob"],
  ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "Escalated", ""],
  ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "", "ABC Team"],
  ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "Escalated", ""],
  ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "", "Smith, Bob"],
  ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "Escalated", ""],
  ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "", "Global Design"],
  ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "Escalated", ""],
  ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "", "Jones, Fred"],
  ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "Escalated", ""],
  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", ""],
  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", "Finance"],
  ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "Escalated", ""]
]

data = array.map {|e| e[0]}.uniq.map { |time| array.select {|e| e[0] == time}.flatten.uniq }
puts data.to_s

# output:
# [
#   ["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""]
#   ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "", "Smith, Bob", "Escalated"]
#   ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "", "ABC Team", "Escalated"]
#   ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "", "Smith, Bob", "Escalated"]
#   ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "", "Global Design", "Escalated"]
#   ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "", "Jones, Fred", "Escalated"]
#   ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "", "Finance", "Escalated"]
# ]
```

Don't know if you want the blank string or not. Without blank string:

```
array.map {|e| e[0]}.uniq.map { |time| array.select {|e| e[0] == time}.flatten.uniq.reject{|e| e.empty?} }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.inject({}) {|h, a| e = h[a[0]] || [a[0]]; e[1] = e[1].nil? || e[1] == "" ? a[1] : e[1]; e[2] = e[2].nil? || e[2] == "" ? a[2] : e[2]; h[a[0]] = e; h }.values
 => [["2011-12-03 01:21:31", "Closed", ""],
 ["2011-11-11 00:42:40", "Escalated", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-10 21:36:11", "Escalated", "ABC Team"],
 ["2011-11-10 18:42:19", "Escalated", "Smith, Bob"],
 ["2011-11-09 22:55:01", "Escalated", "Global Design"],
 ["2011-09-28 18:56:32", "Escalated", "Jones, Fred"],
 ["2011-09-28 07:19:28", "Escalated", "Finance"]]
```

where array os the original array.

Another way:

```
array.each_with_object({}) {|a, h| e = (h[a[0]] ||= []); a.map.with_index {|x, i| e[i] = (e[i] && e[i] != "" ? e[i] : x) } }.values
```